# Javascript not enabled after AJAX call unless page refreshed

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a system that will generate a page that can be filled out online and then sent to a printer.

The system uses AJAX to take data from an existing page and send the data to a java servlet.  The servlet builds the html and sends it back where it is displayed in a separate window.

However, the generated html in the separate window doesn't fire any event (like click) until after it's refreshed.  If I click the "Print" button on the page, nothing happens until I refresh, at which point my print dialog appears.

The AJAX call:

```
function printForm(warrants) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "html",
        url: "AjaxServlet",
        data: {formType: 'printForm', warrants: warrants, headerValues: getHeaderValues()
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var win = window.open();
            win.document.write(data);
        }
    })
}
```

The generated html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE  html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta name="author" content="radelman"/>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/fau.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        h1 { font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 16pt; }
        .s1 { font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 8pt; }
        .s2 { font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 9pt; }
        .s3 { font-family: serif; font-weight: normal; font-size: 10pt; }
        .s3a { font-family: serif; font-weight: bolder; font-size: 10pt; }
        .s4 { font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: normal; font-size: 9pt; }
        .s5 { font-family: serif; font-weight: normal; font-size: 9pt; }
        h2 { font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14pt; }
        .s6 { font-weight: normal; font-size: 14pt; }
        .s7 { font-family: serif; font-weight: normal; font-size: 14pt; }
        .s8 { font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: normal; font-size: 6pt; }
        p { font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: normal; font-size: 12pt; }
        .s9 { font-family: serif; font-weight: normal; font-size: 12pt; }
        td { text-align: center;padding-bottom: 5px;padding-top: 5px;}
        input.skinny{width: 40px;};
        input.superskinny{width: 35px;}
        input.seventyfive{width: 75px;}
        input.sixty{width: 60px;}
        input.sixtyfive{width: 65px;}
        input.seventy{width: 70px;}
        input[type="text"], textarea{
            background-color: lightblue;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }
        input.resize{width: 94%;margin-top: -3px;}
        @media screen {
            div.divFooter {
                display: none;
            }
            div.printButton{
                display: inline;
            }
        }
        @media print {
            div.divFooter {
                position: fixed;
                bottom: 0;
            }
            div.printButton{
                display: none;
            }
            input[type="text"], textarea{
                font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; font-size: 7pt;
            }
        }

    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showMessage(){
            alert("running");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="showMessage()">
    <div class="divFooter" style="font-size: x-small;width: 100%;text-align: right;">
        <span style="float: left;">Arrest/Booking for AGUILAR, JESSE</span>
        <span style="float: right;">BCSO Form #351-045 (Rev. 07/06/11)</span>
    </div>
    <div style="width: 100%;text-align: center;">
        <h1>SHERIFFS OFFICE ARREST &amp; BOOKING SHEET</h1>
    </div>
    <div style="text-align: center;border-collapse: collapse;">
        <table border="1" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; width: 90%;margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 20%;"><p class="s1">Offense Case #</p><input class="resize" type="text" id="txtOffenseCaseNum" name="txtOffenseCaseNum" value=""</td>
                <td style="width: 20%;"><p class="s1">Master Incident #</p><input class="resize" type="text" id="txtMasterIncidentNum" name="txtMasterIncidentNum" value=""/></td>
                <td style="width: 20%;"><p class="s1">Date of Occurrence</p><input class="resize" type="text" id="txtDateOfOccurrence" name="txtDateOfOccurrence" value="" /></td>
                <td style="width: 20%;"><p class="s1">Time of Occurrence</p><input class="resize" type="text" id="txtTimeOfOccurrence" name="txtTimeOfOccurrence" value="09/23/2015 14:27:48" /></td>
                <td style="width: 20%;"><p class="s1">Arresting Agency ORI</p><input class="resize" type="text" id="txtArrestingAgencyORI" name="txtArrestingAgencyORI" value="" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table border="1" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; width: 90%;margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="9" class="s3a" style="width: 100%; background-color: black; color: white;text-align: center;">ARRESTED PERSON INFORMATION</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 24%;"><p class="s1">Name (Last, First, Middle)</p><input class="resize" type="text" id="txtName" name="txtName" value=""/></td>
                <td style="width: 4%;"><p class="s1">Race</p><input size="2" type="text" id="txtRace" name="txtRace" value=""/></td>
                <td style="width: 4%;"><p class="s1">Sex</p><input size="2" type="text" id="txtSex" name="txtSex" value=""/></td>
                <td style="width: 4%;"><p class="s1">Height</p><input size="2" type="text" id="txtHeight" name="txtHeight" value=""/></td>
                <td style="width: 4%;"><p class="s1">Weight</p><input size="2" type="text" id="txtWeight" name="txtWeight" value=""/></td>
                <td style="width: 4%;"><p class="s1">Hair</p><input size="2" type="text" id="txtHair" name="txtHair" value=""/></td>
                <td style="width: 4%;"><p class="s1">Eyes</p><input size="2" type="text" id="txtEyes" name="txtEyes" value=""/></td>
                <td style="width: 17%;"><p class="s1">CIJS SID #</p><input class="resize" type="text" id="txtCIJSSIDNum" name="txtCIJSSIDNum" value="" /></td>
                <td style="width: 17%;"><p class="s1">CIJS SPN #</p><input class="resize" type="text" id="txtCIJSSPNNum" name="txtCIJSSPNNum" value="" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table border="1" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; width: 90%;margin-top: -1px;margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 22%"><p class="s1">Address</p><input class="resize" type="text" id="txtAddress" name="txtAddress" value=""/></td>
                <td style="width: 13%"><p class="s1">Unit Type</p><input class="resize" type="text" id="txtUnitType" name="txtUnitType" value=""/></td>
                <td style="width: 13%"><p class="s1">Unit #</p><input class="resize" type="text" id="txtUnitNum" name="txtUnitNum" value=""/></td>
                <td style="width: 13%"><p class="s1">Complexion</p><input class="resize" type="text" id="txtComplexion" name="txtComplexion" value=""/></td>
                <td style="width: 13%"><p class="s1">Build</p><input class="resize" type="text" id="txtBuild" name="txtBuild" value=""/></td>
                <td style="width: 13%"><p class="s1">Date of Birth</p><input class="resize" type="text" id="txtDateOfBirth" name="txtDateOfBirth" value=""/></td>
                <td style="width: 13%"><p class="s1">Age</p><input class="resize" type="text" id="txtAge" name="txtAge" value=""/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table border="1" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; width: 90%;margin-top: -1px;margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
            <tr>
                <td><p class="s1">City</p><input class="resize" type="text" id="txtCity" name="txtCity" value=""/></td>
                <td><p class="s1">State</p><input class="resize" type="text" id="txtState" name="txtState" value=""/></td>
                <td><p class="s1">Zip Code</p><input class="resize" type="text" id="txtZipCode" name="txtZipCode" value=""/></td>
                <td><p class="s1">Primary Phone</p><input class="resize" type="text" id="txtPrimaryPhone" name="txtPrimaryPhone" value=""/></td>
                <td><p class="s1">Secondary Phone</p><input class="resize" type="text" id="txtSecondaryPhone" name="txtSecondaryPhone" value=""/></td>
                <td><p class="s1">Drivers License</p><input class="resize" type="text" id="txtDriversLicense" name="txtDriversLicense" value=""/></td>
                <td><p class="s1">State</p><input class="resize" type="text" id="txtDriversLicenseState" name="txtDriversLicenseState" value=""/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3"><p class="s1">Aliases / Nicknames / Maiden Name</p><input class="resize" type="text" id="txtAlias" name="txtAlias" value=""/></td>
                <td colspan="2"><p class="s1">Place of Birth</p><input class="resize" type="text" id="txtPlaceOfBirth" name="txtPlaceOfBith" value=""/></td>
                <td colspan="1"><p class="s1">Citizenship</p><input class="resize" type="text" id="txtCitizenship" name="txtCitizenship" value=""/></td>
                <td colspan="1"><p class="s1">SSN</p><input class="resize" type="text" id="txtSocialSecurityNum" name="txtSocialSecurityNum" value=""/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4"><p class="s1">Scars, Marks, Tattoos, Amputations</p><input class="resize" type="text" id="txtScars" name="txtScars" value=""/></td>
                <td colspan="5"><p class="s1">Miscellaneous Number(s)</p><input class="resize" type="text" id="txtMiscNum" name="txtMiscNum" value=""/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table border="1" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; width: 90%;margin-top: -1px;margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 20%;"><p class="s1">Occupation</p><input class="resize" type="text" id="txtOccupation" name="txtOccupation" value=""/></td>
                <td style="width: 25%;"><p class="s1">Employer</p><input class="resize" type="text" id="txtEmployer" name="txtEmployer" value=""/></td>
                <td style="width: 20%;"><p class="s1">Student</p>
                    <input type="radio" id="radioIsStudent" name="radioIsStudent" value="yes" />Yes   
                    <input type="radio" checked id="radioIsStudent" name="radioIsStudent" value="no" />No
                </td>
                <td style="width: 20%;"><p class="s1">School</p><input class="resize" type="text" id="txtSchool" name="txtSchool" value=""/></td>
                <td style="width: 10%"><p class="s1">Education Level</p><input class="resize" type="text" id="txtEducationLevel" name="txtEducationLevel" value=""/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding-bottom: 6px;"><p class="s1">Emergency Contact (Last, First)</p><input class="resize" type="text" id="txtEmergencyContact" name="txtEmergencyContact" value=""/></td>
                <td style="padding-bottom: 6px;"><p class="s1">Address</p><input class="resize" type="text" id="txtContactAddress" name="txtContactAddress" value=""/></td>
                <td style="padding-bottom: 6px;"><p class="s1">City</p><input class="resize" type="text" id="txtContactCity" name="txtContactCity" value=""/></td>
                <td style="padding-bottom: 6px;"><p class="s1">State</p><input class="resize" type="text" id="txtContactState" name="txtContactState" value=""/></td>
                <td style="padding-bottom: 6px;"><p class="s1">Zip Code</p><input class="resize" type="text" id="txtContactZip" name="txtContactZip" value=""/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table border="1" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; width: 90%;margin-top: -1px;margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
            <tr style="background-color: black; color: white;border: none;">
                <td class="s3a" style="width: 20%;border: none;">OFFENSE CODE</td>
                <td class="s3a" style="width: 35%;border: none;">CHARGE DESCRIPTION</td>
                <td class="s3a" style="width: 20%;border: none;">WARRANT #</td>
                <td class="s3a" style="width: 5%;border: none;">WARRANT TYPE</td>
                <td class="s3a" style="width: 20%;border: none;">ISSUED BY</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding-top:5px;padding-bottom: 3px;"><input type="text" class="resize" id="txtOffenseCode1" name="txtOffenseCode1" value=""/> </td>
                <td style="padding-top:5px;padding-bottom: 3px;"><input type="text" class="resize" id="txtChargeDescription1" name="txtChargeDescription1" value="" /></td>
                <td style="padding-top:5px;padding-bottom: 3px;"><input type="text" class="resize" id="txtWarrantNum1" name="txtWarrantNum1" value="" /></td>
                <td style="padding-top:5px;padding-bottom: 3px;"><input type="text" class="resize" id="txtWarrantType1" name="txtWarrantType1" value="" /></td>
                <td style="padding-top:5px;padding-bottom: 3px;"><input type="text" class="resize" id="txtIssuedBy1" name="txtIssuedBy1" value="" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding-top:5px;padding-bottom: 3px;"><input type="text" class="resize" id="txtOffenseCode1" name="txtOffenseCode1" value="000000000091100"/> </td>
                <td style="padding-top:5px;padding-bottom: 3px;"><input type="text" class="resize" id="txtChargeDescription1" name="txtChargeDescription1" value="" /></td>
                <td style="padding-top:5px;padding-bottom: 3px;"><input type="text" class="resize" id="txtWarrantNum1" name="txtWarrantNum1" value="" /></td>
                <td style="padding-top:5px;padding-bottom: 3px;"><input type="text" class="resize" id="txtWarrantType1" name="txtWarrantType1" value="" /></td>
                <td style="padding-top:5px;padding-bottom: 3px;"><input type="text" class="resize" id="txtIssuedBy1" name="txtIssuedBy1" value="" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table border="1" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; width: 90%;margin-top: -1px;margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;page-break-after: always;">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="9" class="s3a" style="width: 100%; background-color: black; color: white;text-align: center;">ARREST DETAILS</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><p class="s1">Location of Arrest</p><input type="text" class="resize" id="txtLocationOfArrest" name="txtLocationOfArrest" value="" /></td>
                <td colspan="2"><p class="s1">Date of Arrest</p><input type="text" class="resize" id="txtDateOfArrest" name="txtDateOfArrest" value="" /></td>
                <td colspan="2"><p class="s1">Time of Arrest</p><input type="text" class="resize" id="txtTimeOfArrest" name="txtTimeOfArrest" value="" /></td>
                <td colspan="2"><p class="s1">District / RA</p><input type="text" class="resize" id="txtDistrictRA" name="txtDistrictRA" value="" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3"><p class="s1">Condition of Prisoner</p><input type="text" class="resize" id="txtConditionOfPrisoner" name="txtConditionOfPrisoner" value="" /></td>
                <td colspan="3"><p class="s1">Special Needs</p><input type="text" class="resize" id="txtSpecialNeeds" name="txtSpecialNeeds" value="" /></td>
                <td colspan="2"><p class="s1">Disposition</p><input type="text" class="resize" id="txtDisposition" name="txtDisposition" value="" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table border="1" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; width: 90%;margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
            <tr>
                <td width="15%"><p class="s1">Operate Vehicle</p><p class="s4">
                        <input type="radio" id="rdoOperateVehicle" name="rdoOperateVehicle" value="yes" />Yes
                        <input checked type="radio" id="rdoOperateVehicle" name="rdoOperateVehicle" value="no" />No
                </td>
                <td width="14%"><p class="s1">VIN or License Plate</p><input type="text" class="resize" id="txtVIN" name="txtVIN" value="" /></td>
                <td width="14%"><p class="s1">Make</p><input type="text" class="resize" id="txtMake" name="txtMake" value="" /></td>
                <td width="14%"><p class="s1">Model</p><input type="text" class="resize" id="txtModel" name="txtModel" value="" /></td>
                <td width="14%"><p class="s1">Year</p><input type="text" class="resize" id="txtYear" name="txtYear" value="" /></td>
                <td width="14%"><p class="s1">Color</p><input type="text" class="resize" id="txtColor" name="txtColor" value="" /></td>
                <td width="14%"><p class="s1">Hazardous Material</p>
                    <input type="radio" id="rdoHazardousMaterial" name="rdoHazardousMaterial" value="yes"/>Yes
                    <input checked type="radio" id="rdoHazardousMaterial" name="rdoHazardousMaterial" value="no" />No
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table border="1" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; width: 90%;margin-top: -1px;margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 25%;"><p class="s1">Vehicle Impounded</p><p class="s4">
                        <input type="radio" id="rdoVehicleImpounded" name="rdoVehicleImpounded" value="yes" />Yes
                        <input checked type="radio" id="rdoVehicleImpounded" name="rdoVehicleImpounded" value="no" />No
                </td>
                <td style="width: 50%;"><p class="s1">Location</p><input type="text" class="resize" id="txtImpoundLocation" name="txtImpoundLocation" value="" /></td>
                <td style="width: 25%"><p class="s1">Phone #</p><input type="text" class="resize" id="txtImpoundPhone" name="txtImpoundPhone" value="" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p class="s1">Property in Property Room</p>
                    <input type="radio" id="rdoPropertyRoom" name="rdoPropertyRoom" value="yes"/>Yes
                    <input checked type="radio" id="rdoPropertyRoom" name="rdoPropertyRoom" value="no"/>No
                </td>
                <td><p class="s1">Location</p><input type="text" class="resize" id="txtPropertyLocation" name="txtPropertyLocation" value="" /></td>
                <td><p class="s1">Phone #</p><input type="text" class="resize" id="txtPropertyPhone" name="txtPropertyPhone" value="" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table border="1" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; width: 90%;margin-top: -1px;margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5" class="s3a" style="width: 100%; background-color: black; color: white;text-align: center;">VICTIM NOTIFICATION</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 20%"><p class="s1">Victim Notification Phone #</p><input type="text" class="resize" id="txtVictimPhone" name="txtVictimPhone" value="" /></td>
                <td style="width: 20%;"><p class="s1">VINE PIN #</p><input type="text" class="resize" id="txtVinePin" name="txtVinePin" value="" /></td>
                <td style="width: 20%;"><p class="s1">Victim Declines Notification</p>
                    <input type="radio" id="rdoDeclinesNotification" name="rdoDeclinesNotification" value="yes" />Yes
                    <input checked type="radio" id="rdoDeclinesNotification" name="rdoDeclinesNotification" value="no">No
                </td>
                <td colspan="2" style="width: 40%"><p class="s1">Comments</p><input type="text" class="resize" id="txtVictimComments" name="txtVictimComments" value="" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5" class="s3a" style="width: 100%; background-color: black; color: white;text-align: center;">FACTS OF ARREST</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 30%;"><p class="s1">Arresting Agency</p><input type="text" class="resize" id="txtArrestingAgency" name="txtArrestingAgency" value="" /></td>
                <td style="width: 30%;"><p class="s1">Address</p><input type="text" class="resize" id="txtArrestingAddress" name="txtArrestingAddress" value="" /></td>
                <td style="width: 20%;"><p class="s1">City</p><input type="text" class="resize" id="txtArrestingCity" name="txtArrestingCity" value="" /></td>
                <td style="width: 10%;"><p class="s1">State</p><input type="text" class="resize" id="txtArrestingState" name="txtArrestingState" value="" /></td>
                <td style="width: 10%;"><p class="s1">Zip Code</p><input type="text" class="resize" id="txtArrestingZip" name="txtArrestingZip" value="" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table border="1" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; width: 90%;margin-top: -1px;margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 30%;"><p class="s1">Complainant / Victim Name</p><input type="text" class="resize" id="txtComplaintantName" name="txtComplaintantName" value="" /></td>
                <td style="width: 30%;"><p class="s1">Address</p><input type="text" class="resize" id="txtComplaintantAddress" name="txtComplaintantAddress" value="" /></td>
                <td style="width: 20%;"><p class="s1">City</p><input type="text" class="resize" id="txtComplaintantCity" name="txtComplaintantCity" value="" /></td>
                <td style="width: 10%;"><p class="s1">State</p><input type="text" class="resize" id="txtComplaintantState" name="txtComplaintantState" value="" /></td>
                <td style="width: 10%;"><p class="s1">Zip Code</p><input type="text" class="resize" id="txtComplaintantZip" name="txtComplaintantZip" value="" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 30%;"><p class="s1">Witness Name</p><input type="text" class="resize" id="txtWitnessName" name="txtWitnessName" value="" /></td>
                <td style="width: 30%;"><p class="s1">Address</p><input type="text" class="resize" id="txtWitnessAddress" name="txtWitnessAddress" value="" /></td>
                <td style="width: 20%;"><p class="s1">City</p><input type="text" class="resize" id="txtWitnessCity" name="txtWitnessCity" value="" /></td>
                <td style="width: 10%;"><p class="s1">State</p><input type="text" class="resize" id="txtWitnessState" name="txtWitnessState" value="" /></td>
                <td style="width: 10%;"><p class="s1">Zip Code</p><input type="text" class="resize" id="txtWitnessZip" name="txtWitnessZip" value="" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table border="1" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse; width: 90%;margin-top: -1px;margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 8%;"><p class="s1">Badge</p><input type="text" class="resize" id="txtArrestingBadge1" name="txtArrestingBadge1" value="" /></td>
                <td style="width: 17%;"><p class="s1">Arresting Officer 1</p><input type="text" class="resize" id="txtArrestingOfficer1" name="txtArrestingOfficer1" value="" /></td>
                <td style="width: 8%;"><p class="s1">Badge</p><input type="text" class="resize" id="txtArrestingBadge2" name="txtArrestingBadge2" value="" /></td>
                <td style="width: 17%;"><p class="s1">Arresting Officer 2</p><input type="text" class="resize" id="txtArrestingOfficer2" name="txtArrestingOfficer2" value="" /></td>
                <td style="width: 8%;"><p class="s1">Badge</p><input type="text" class="resize" id="txtTransportBadge" name="txtTransportBadge" value="" /></td>
                <td style="width: 17%;"><p class="s1">Transporting Officer</p><input type="text" class="resize" id="txtTransportOfficer" name="txtTransportOfficer" value="" /></td>
                <td style="width: 8%;"><p class="s1">Badge</p><input type="text" class="resize" id="txtApprovingBadge" name="txtApprovingBadge" value="" /></td>
                <td style="width: 17%;"><p class="s1">Approving Officer</p><input type="text" class="resize" id="txtApprovingOfficer" name="txtApprovingOfficer" value="" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <h3>SHERIFFS OFFICE 
            <span style="padding-left: 2%;padding-right: 2%;" class="s6">&#x2666;</span>
            <span class="s7"> </span>200 MAIN <span style="padding-left: 2%; padding-right: 2%;" class="s6">&#x2666;</span>
            <span class="s7"> </span>SOMEWHERE, SOMESTATE 00000
        </h3>
        <h2>Mental Health Diversion Questions</h2>
        <table border="0" class="s9" cellspacing="0" style="width: 99%;margin-top: -1px;margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
            <tr style="border:none;">
                <td style="width: 70%;border: none;text-align: left;margin-left: 20%;">
                    1.   Have you ever been diagnosed as having a mental illness by a doctor or a mental health professional? (Check 1)
                </td>
                <td style="width: 30%;border: none;">
                    <input type="radio" id="rdoDiagnosedMental" name="rdoDiagnosedMental" value="yes" />Yes
                    <span class="s9">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                    <input checked type="radio" id="rdoDiagnosedMental" name="rdoDiagnosedMental" value="no" />No
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 70%;border: none;text-align: left;margin-left: 20%;">
                    2.   Have you ever or are currently taking any medications for mental illness? (Check 1)
                </td>
                <td style="width: 30%;border: none;">
                    <input type="radio" id="rdoTakingMeds" name="rdoTakingMeds" value="yes" />Yes
                    <span class="s9">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                    <input checked type="radio" id="rdoTakingMeds" name="rdoTakingMeds" value="no" />No
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 70%;border: none;text-align: left;margin-left: 20%;">
                    3.   Have you ever tried to kill yourself? (Check 1)
                </td>
                <td style="width: 30%;border: none;">
                    <input type="radio" id="rdoTriedKillSelf" name="rdoTriedKillSelf" value="yes" />Yes
                    <span class="s9">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                    <input checked type="radio" id="rdoTriedKillSelf" name="rdoTriedKillSelf" value="no" />No
                </td>                    
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 70%;border: none;text-align: left;margin-left: 20%;">
                    4.   Do you currently have thoughts of killing yourself? (Check 1)
                </td>
                <td style="width: 30%;border: none;">
                    <input type="radio" id="rdoKillThought" name="rdoKillThought" value="yes" />Yes
                    <span class="s9">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
                    <input checked type="radio" id="rdoKillThought" name="rdoKillThought" value="no" />No
                </td> 
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br/>
        <div style="width: 100%;text-align: center;">
            ***These questions are to be asked to arrested person as by required by procedure 601, and a Directive issued by the Sheriff?s Office.***
            <br/>
            <div class="printButton" style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">
                <button onclick="window.print()">Print</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        </p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: its not the ajax issue.. since you didn't provide your event trigger, make sure you use `on` or `live` method so that whenever your content change, the event handler is still intact.

Comment: try placing your `<script>` tags in the end of the body.

Comment: @cylua2 that's irrelevant in this case. he's not even using jQuery in the document he's creating.

Comment: @cylua2 `live` has been deprecated and removed from jQuery for a long long time.

Comment: without seeing the error/console I have a feeling your DOM is not yet ready when you bind the elements.

Comment: he isn't binding events to elements, he's using onevent attributes. so that's irrelevant too.

Comment: @KevinB so why does he need jquery + another javascript file?

Comment: ah, figure he just rewrite everything on doc.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: @epascarello: No errors on the console

Comment: @Saar he may not need them, but the functionality he's looking at is the window.print() at the bottom, which should work regardless of whether or not those other scripts work.

Comment: @Saar:  Part of a template.  Just didn't remove it.

Comment: do you need a win.document.close()? it's specified as optional in the docs, but i don't see anything else that could be causing this.

Comment: I vote for trying `document.close()` after document.write.

Comment: @KevinB:  Give the man a ceegar.  Write that up as an answer, kind sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to close the document for it to become useable after writing to it.

```
var win = window.open();
win.document.write(data);
win.document.close();
```

This isn't needed when working with the main document because it will be automagically closed when the dom is done parsing, but you do have to do this when you open a new window and write to it.